# Probability of $n$ unique integers chosen randomly from $\{ 0, \ldots, n-1 \}$

Tags: random, percentages

For an array with range $n$ filled with random numbers ranging from 0 (inclusive) to $n$ (exclusive), what percent of the array contains unique numbers?

I was able to make a program that tries to calculate this with repeated trials and ended up with ~63.212%.

My Question is what equation could calculate this instead of me just repeating trials.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please consider going through the help center. As it stand right now, the question is almost certainly going to be closed due to 1. Formatting Problems 2. Unclear what you are asking 3. No showing your own work. Have fun here!

Comment: Its' pretty clear what he's asking and he made a program to evaluate it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of expectation values?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is: I worked out what I thought the answer should be and got a number close to $1/e$. This is nowhere near 62%.

Comment: Don't you think the answer depends upon $n$?  Why or why not?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Have you tried $1-\frac1e$? Maybe it's just an inversion in the program somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique numbers" : all numbers from $0$ to $n$ (so $n+1$ many) occur at most once?

Comment: Could examples be given - does $\{1,1,1,2\}$ count as $0.25$ or $0.5$?

Comment: You don't mean "unique numbers", you mean "distinct numbers". Google translate has failed you; the English word "unique" does not mean "distinct".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is suspiciously close to $1-1/e$.  The fraction of values represented exactly $k$ times in your array should be close to $\exp(-1)/k!$, so it looks like your program counted the number of distinct values in the array, rather than the number of values represented only once.

Answer (score 0):

If my interpretation is correct there are $n^n$ equiprobable array fillings, of which $n!$ have all numbers occurring at most once.

So you get as the answer: $$\frac{n!}{n^n}$$ and [Stirling's approximation formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) says that:

$$n! \sim n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi} e^{-n}$$ This should allow one to compute the limit of this fraction as $n$ gets larger.